# How can I reuse function by making it more flexible

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a function in my NodeJs Api which will return objects in an array that meet certain criteria. In this case I am using `findIndex` to do this. My question is to be able to reuse the function is there a way to pass in the values like `[phones]` in `data.phones.findIndex` so that if i would want emails i could just pass in emails without having to create a new function ? Further more can i pass in the field like `[type]` in the `item.type` ? As for the phones part I know I could call it like this

```
getWorkPhone(myObj.phones, 'Work')
```

and remove the `phones` and make it `data.findIndex` . Final Part would be how can i get all indexes should there be more then one since `findIndex` returns only the first match ?

```
 const getWorkPhone = (data, myValue) => {
    const index = data.phones.findIndex(item => item.type === myValue && item.dflt === true)
    console.log(index)
    console.log(data.phones[index].number)
  }
```

Comment: myObject.phones as a phones propery?

Comment: That is, is `data` itself an homogenous array of values with `type` and `dflt` properties that behave in the specific manner? If so, then `data.phones` may be making the problem appear harder: `getDefaultValueOfType(data /* myObj.phones, or perhaps myObj.phones.phones? */, 'SomeType')`. The second question should be a separate SO question.

Comment: in this sample myObj holds diffrent arrays like phones , emails etc. Like i said i could pass the myObj.phones in. But how could I pass the item.xxxx meaning the field name in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `filter` to get a list of all 'things' in an array that meet a certain condition.

So perhaps, this is a nice syntax:

```
const workNumbers = numbers.filter(phoneFilter('work'));
```

Then the responsibility of your `phoneFilter` function is to return a function that works with `filter`.

```
function phoneFilter(type) {

   return (item) => item.type === type;

}
```

Of course, this is not *that* different from doing everything in-line, but it does add some nice semantic meaning. Doing everything without helper functions looks like this (which I think is still pretty obvious/readable):

```
const workNumbers = numbers.filter(item => item.type === 'work');
```

A third way is to define a function that does *both* the `.filter()` invocation, and the filtering itself, but I think it doesn't compose as nicely:

```
function myPhoneFilter(numbers, type) {
  return numbers.filter(item => item.type === type);
}

const workNumbers = myPhoneFilter(numbers, 'work');
```

For simple use-cases such as this, I would probably not even bother writing helper functions, because the the inline version is already so obvious: